# Does GCHandle.Alloc prevent paging?

Tags: c#, memory

Suppose you do this:

```
byte[] arr = null;
GCHandle handle;
try {
    arr = new byte[1024];
    handle = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    
    // Do something with arr
}
finally {
    if (arr != null) {
        Array.Clear(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Is it possible for `arr` to be paged to the disk?

I know that `GCHandle.Alloc` prevents the `GC` from moving the data around, but does it prevent **paging to the disk**? If somebody were to use up all the systems memory, would it be possible that `arr` is written to the disk?

Comment: The only thing GCHandle.Alloc with GCHandleType.Pinned does is instruct the GC not to move the managed object around. It only affects the managed memory. Disk swapping is done by the OS and thus outside of the domain of the GC. They are different layers: the managed memory layer which is managed by the GC, and the virtual memory layer (physical memory and swap file) which is managed by the OS, whereas the GC requests and returns memory blocks from and to the OS.

Comment: It is possible to tell the OS kernel to keep certain pages in memory, but GCHandle does not do this, nor does it need to. As far as a single process is concerned, virtual memory never moves, because it's *virtual*